# Any system I can use for a Monster Hunter (VG) RPG?

Tags: game-recommendation

I've been playing with my pals lately, from Horror to Dark Fantasy, using both 4e and the rules on Savage Worlds, we like rules-light and easy to learn systems.

Lately we've been playing Capcom's Monster Hunter game, in which you create a human hunter and fight dragons, giant bugs, crabs and weird beasts by wearing a variety of weapons.

One could think I can use any system to convert MH, however there are some issues:

- The weapons here can execute unique perks, such as the Great Sword being able to charge a powerful attack and work as a shield, there's a lance that can fire shotgun bullets, an axe that can turn into a great sword, lances are the only weapons what can block every attack, bows have infinite ammo and can cause arrow rains... every weapon is basically a class of its own.
- You NEVER level up and all of the stats are modified according to the armor you're wearing. Basically every hunter is the same stat-wise.
- Monsters have breakable parts that affect battle. Say, the Barroth, a mud wyvern, can had its tail and bulldozer-like forehead broken so it can't use its mud attack with ease, and breaking the wing spikes of a Barroth, an ice-tiger wyvern, makes him trip when landing after a flyby attack, a Blangonga, a giant ape, will lose its control over its minions when the fangs are broken.
- The game uses items such as potions, mega potions, steaks to heal your stamina, etc.
- Weapons lose sharpness when used and you must use items to keep them sharp or else they will bounce off the monsters and deal no damage.
- Basically every hunter can use every weapon, so you can switch classes on the go, and since you don't level up you always use the same moves. Monsters DO get harder, and that's when you have to upgrade your weapons and armor.
- Well, there are skills, but they're all battle-oriented feats, like "Sharpness +1", "Bombardier", "Attack Up", "Evasion Up", etc.

I was thinking on doing it with Savage Worlds, however there are NOT large scale battles in MH games and combats should be lengthy, since some times you fight monsters the size of a mountain, bombarding them before they can reach a city and then facing them afoot.

Then I thought about 4e, but I don't know how to pull it out with that one...

I'd like to have a system flexible as Savage Worlds, but that uses HP mechanics. I would like to see something that lets me tweak the characters, something WITHOUT classes and that's not very complex, something that doesn't involves book keeping in excess,

Comment: Any generic system can pull this off with more or less work (e.g., GURPS, Fate, BRP...), so we are going to need some more specific requirements in order for this to be on topic.

Comment: Hmmmm ok, what else info can I add?

Comment: As I said, this can be done by *any* generic system. You're going to have to give us more about what you want in a recommended system, outside of "can it emulate X". Things like, I don't know, the colour of the book cover and whether it was published in 1983. Details about what *you* want the system to be like.

Comment: Indeed. I would be interested as to why you've discounted Savage Worlds given that you have experience with the system. I believe you would be able to do the above using it, and want to know why you have chosen not to.

Comment: Because of what I mention abotu SW ending battles too quickly. Monsters in MH inflict a variety of ailments that work odd on SW, such as poison which in SW is LETHAL as there's not HP on the system, and the game itself relies a lot on which items you can use as a hunter, plus weapons on SW are merely the same and give you not many reasons to switch. I've been trying to work arround it, but some stuff such as de Hunting Horn that heals you and buffs you work better on a system that uses actual hitpoints.