# Games with dynamic combat system

Tags: game-recommendation, campaign-development

I'm building a campaign around CAPCOM Monster Hunter videogame, I only know 3 games, D&D (3.5e, 4e,5e), Roleage ( a spanish d100 game that has a duengeon siege progresion feeling), and Anima: Beyond Fantasy ( another Spanish rpg).

We ( the players and me) are hombrewing a lot of content and decided to use Anima combat system we feeled it was the best of the ones we knew.

I tried to research a bit and found PDQ Sharp but it doesn't adecuate entirely to our idea of combat with bigger tan you monsters.

What the system must have:

- Health points: a mean to track,damage and healing
- No Hit or miss: the game should give options for various degrees of hit for the same objective
- dynamic turns: for example in anima after rolling initiative you declare your action and some action reduce your rolled initiative, until your turn reaches you , you can be interupted/atacked/prepare defense against you...

I know the existence of these two questions:
[This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/29026/any-system-i-can-use-for-a-monster-hunter-vg-rpg)
 and [this other](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62435/how-can-i-make-a-pathfinder-campaign-like-the-monster-hunter-video-game-series)

Hope this edit is more clear , not that much specific and too broad.
Thank you

Comment: I wish I had a good option.  A lot of my friends and I are all into Monster Hunter and considering how to bring it into tabletop.  Based on what you're asking for, you're probably going to have to build a game from the ground upwards.

Comment: I think Anima could be a good fit as long as you ask the players not to be too powerful.  Was there a reason you're moving away from this option?

Comment: We are simply researching other options, mayby there is some system we aren't aware off that can help us or give ideas,

Comment: Asking for a list of games for a research survey is much too broad for Stack Exchange, and this is made broader still by accepting house rules and homebrew. To gather lists of existing games like what you're looking for, you probably want a [discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) instead of a Stack, as you'll get more helpful responses in a place intended for open-ended discussion.

Comment: Should I then close this question? I know i could reduce the scope to two or three options but I don't know if this would be enough

Comment: @xerido Weirdly, this question is both too broad *and* too narrow. It's too broad because of the house-rule thing that SevenSidedDie mentioned, and because there's no clear criteria for what would make one possible answer better than any others; It's too narrow because the combination of features you need is highly specific and unusual. I think a possible solution to both of these problems is to rank the features you want in order of importance; What is it about a MoHun game that you believe is most important for the campaign you want to run?

Comment: You might want to look at some of our other successful system recommendation questions for inspiration on how to improve this one.

Comment: Changed a bit the question, hope this is a better question, Thank you all for the help

Comment: OK, you now have clear criteria and aren't asking for houserules; That's a definite improvement. But there's something more we still need: If there's multiple answers that seem to meet your needs, how do we tell which is best?

Comment: i think the best answer would be the one that explained a bit about the game system, and if it had more than only one game explained would be the best. But I see it can be broad too :S, back to thinking it better out